# Application size doesn't reduce after deleting bundle content

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bundle

I have an iphone application with custom bundle in resources with hi-resoultion photos (sized about 150mb). I need to reduce application size, so i do an update and remove this bundle from resources, but when i apply new update on installed application, its size remains the same.

Is it possible to "update" application resouces after update from appstore?

Comment: I do not understand the last question.

Comment: Re the first part: Where do you see the size of the boundle? Why don't you just have a look into it and see what it is that takes the size?

Comment: Do a "clean" first (COMMAND-K) and build again.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the new Update that you are providing (with less resources) are not replacing the existing app (with More Resources) ???? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question.

The problem was that installing application directly from xcode to the phone didn't act the same way like installing a new app version from appstore. The version on the iphone kept old resources in bundle after installing via xcode. But I emulated situatuion like "appstore new version install" using TestFlight. I made 2 different version with diferrent bundles and installed one after another. The size of app changed! The problem was solved.

Maybe it was some bugs - stangely cleaning, removid derived data, didn't help at all.

Comment: Did you try deleting it off the phone before installing via xcode?

Comment: I wanted to simulate installation of a new version from appstore, i couldn't erase it from the phone.